# Using Javascript to update table/div contents during page load

Tags: javascript, perl, asynchronous, execution, continuous

I currently have a Perl script that prints some HTML tables and divs, prints an opening `<script type="text/javascript">` tag, and then forks off a few processes to collect some data to fill the tables.  These forked processes asynchronously print JavaScript `document.getElementById` statements to fill the table and divs.  My Perl script waits on all of the child processes and once they have all returned prints the ending `</script>` tag.

Although maybe not overly elegent, this is how I'm filling an ordered table with asynchronously returned results. I'd really like to see the contents of the table load as results are returned, but Firefox doesn't appear to render the JavaScript until receiving the `</script>` tag. Is there a way I can force the rendering of each `document.getElementById` statement as it is sent to the browser?  I could print opening and closing script tags with each statement, but this seemed excessive.  I'm not sure how else to deal with displaying a bunch of asynchronous statements, but I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do it with separate script blocks.  No browser is going to start running a `<script>` block until it's complete; it *can't* due to the semantics of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confused. `document.getElementById()` is not a *statement*, it is not a language construct, but a *method* of the `document` *host object*.

`document.getElementById` does nothing that would cause the browser to rerender the page. It simply selects the element with a given id in the `document`.

It is hard to say anything without knowing the reasons for this constantly updating output, but you may have no choice but to use separate `<script>` blocks in order to execute them continously.

Comment: thank you for the clarification of my description and your solutions.